# Reopening AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avcam

I have an application which takes some pictures.
My whole application is based on the [AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/) sample code from WWDC 2010.
I've messed with it a lot and yet, up until now I can't figure out how to release the camera view properly which releases the camera session...

All i'm trying to do is the following:

- Open camera view controller
- Take some photos
- Close camera view Controller
- Open it again

The second time I push the viewController the session is lost, preview is not available and capturing is not available as well. I've published [full example code on github](https://github.com/eladg/AVCam-WithDestroySession).

My workaround for the issue was not to release the camera at all so the Camera View Controller acts as a Singleton, which I think is **not** the right way. moreover, with this behavior I couldn't figure out a way to support camera when application went to the background (phone call for example).

**Please advice**. How do I destruct the camera session? and is it important to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added the following message to `AVCamCaptureManager`

```
- (void) destroySession {

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManagerSessionWillEnd:)]) {
        [delegate captureManagerSessionWillEnd:self];
    }

    // remove the device inputs
    [session removeInput:[self videoInput]];
    [session removeInput:[self audioInput]];

    // release
    [session release];

    // remove AVCamRecorder
    [recorder release];

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManagerSessionEnded:)]) {
        [delegate captureManagerSessionEnded:self];
    }
}
```

I'm calling `destroySession` when the viewController holding the camera get close (on my example it's `-closeCamera:` of `AVCamViewController`).

For the full working example, you're welcome to download [AVCam-CameraReleaseTest](https://github.com/eladg/AVCam-WithDestroySession) on github.com

Comment: helped a lot thx. If you use AVCam as a ModalViewController you can just call [captureManager destroySession] in the dealloc Method.

Answer (score 0):

G

I think that may help you have a look .

http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/

Comment: I already have an application that captures photos and save it to the library... As I wrote, problem is, how do I close the session properly so it can be reopen???

Comment: i also faced this problem but where i got the solution by doing this thing [session removeInput:input];
   input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:nil];
       
       [session addInput:input]; i removed the previous input and then add the new one it helps me to alloc each time a new input and i able to click each time a new picture with opening and closing the camera and i have done it in a view not in a singleton class and one more thing i am not present modelling my camera view i am just adding it i hope it may help you

Comment: Thanks Ballu!! your comment help me a lot to fix the issue! I will post the full answer as soon as I fix some display issue with my "VideoPreviewView".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really does the job, BUT it also makes some weird thing: I call it on the controller dealloc method. About a second after closing the controller (probably the dealloc get called...) I get for about 0.5 a red effect on the top bar like there was some crash. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: @bashan Just call it on ViewWillDisappear 
and call the restore session on ViewWillAppear